# Scroll To Particular View

Tags: android, scrollview

How to scroll to a particular view?

For example: I have a 3 TextBox/EditText with name A, B, C.

When Textbox A got focus, I want to scroll the layout towards the lower portion of TextBox B.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at help centre to see how you should be asking good questions.

Comment: I tried using scroll to and scroll by but so it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
private final void focusOnView(){
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                your_scrollview.scrollTo(0, your_EditBox.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
```

this may help you

Comment: I try this one using scroll to but its not working. Please Help me.